# Jquery select only first ul inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `ul` in `div`. And I have another `ul` inside `li`. I need to select only first `ul` which located inside the `div`. How to achieve that in jquery.

The markup.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="another-div">
      <ul class="first-ul">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <li>Fifth</li>
        <li>
          <ul class="second-ul">
            <li>First</li>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Fourth</li>
            <li>Fifth</li>
          </ul>        
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the `first-li` using only `parent` class. I have tried `$('.parent > ul')` but this is not working. and `$('.parent ul')` but this selects both ul. I don't want to use `first-ul` class or anything.

Comment: Try : $('.parent li')[0] as $('.parent > ul') look for just next element.

Comment: `$('.parent ul:has(ul)')` or `$('.parent ul:eq(0)')` , using filter `$('.parent ul').filter(function(){return $(this).parents('ul').length==0;})`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the first ul in the following way also:

```
$('.parent ul:first li:first').css('color', 'blue');
```

ul:first will select the first ul in div with class as parent

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/vgj13oo9/).

Answer (score 4):

**Like this:**

```js
$("div > ul").addClass('selected');
```

```css
ul:not(.selected) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="another-div">
      <ul class="first-ul">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <li>Fifth</li>
        <li>
          <ul class="second-ul">
            <li>First</li>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Fourth</li>
            <li>Fifth</li>
          </ul>        
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? @DaMaxContent

Comment: The only way to tell that the class "selected" was added is to open the developer console. a simple `<style>.selected{background:red;}</style>` would be nice

Comment: or even better change the JS to alter the style attribute, if simplicity is what you are aiming for

Comment: Oh, I know, but OP don't need to see any `visualization` and don't want to `addClass` , I just write `addClass` for example, OP just need to select first `ul` . @DaMaxContent

Comment: However, say a newbie to jquery walks in and looks at your code... He will have no idea what happenned

Comment: Yes, but looks like OP found what's happened, but you right, thanks for tip. @DaMaxContent